# How to understand RecyclerView properly

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

I have watched a lot of videos on `RecyclerView` but I am very confused on whether the `ViewHolder` is an adapter that changes the view or does it really just represent each item that is displayed on the screen.

How can I understand the concept more?

Comment: "it really just represent each item that is displayed on the screen"  -exactly

Comment: And that representation (viewholder) is repeated a number of  times (mainly equals the count of data in the list of elements you pass to the adapter)

Comment: @MohamedHamza hey so isn't the view holder an adapter itself, like ur saying it represents each item view shown on the screen so how would that work and are there any good resources that you would recommend for me to learn more valuable information for recycler view.

Comment: Have a look at the doc: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview. For more, just Google "android recyclerview", tons of good articles about it are already out there.

Comment: This is a bit of a broad question, and is saved probably because it has attracted a thoughtful answer. But it's worth noting that "how can I understand this" is a bit hard to answer, since everyone learns differently. "Read the manual" and "do some tutorials" might sound like trivial answers, but they're also correct `:=)`.

Answer (score 7):

Let's see if this helps.

The general job of any list-style view would be to display a long chain of views, each representing a piece of data, most likely from a list.

Now imagine we consider the simplest implementation, where it draws all those views when it is created and allows you to scroll through them. This is obviously very inefficient for performance as a long list would require a lot of processing all at once.

`RecyclerView` aims to solve this and only creates enough views to fit on the screen and when scrolling, changes the content of those views seamlessly to reflect more data.

Now these views are created initially as empty blueprints and the `RecyclerView` wraps them inside something called a `ViewHolder`, which can not only hold the view but also pointers to different parts of the view, which saves doing even more work every time new data is displayed. Then initially and when scrolling, the `RecyclerView` 'binds' the relevant data to view holders.

The job of the adapter is to tie this process together and has three methods that require you to provide a concrete implementation:

- `getItemCount` - expected to return how many items there are in the full dataset
- `onCreateViewHolder` - create a view holder representing a generic row
- `onBindViewHolder` - bind data to a view holder, therefore updating the rows content when given the view holder and the position in the dataset that should be bound

Comment: thanks for the help but what do you mean by recycler wraps this view to the view holder and how is that different from the adapter binding it to the view holder. Also so does the view holder represent each item text that is displayed on the screen @HenryTwist

Comment: So say there is enough room for 6 items on the screen, the RecyclerView will request 6 rows to be created without any data yet. Then it will ask the adapter to bind the data to those rows. So the view holder creation stage doesn't involve any of your data, it's the binding that ties your data to each view holder.